# Creating Html Element with onclick() event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I've been working at this for the last hour, but I am still unable to get the expected output... All I want is to create an HTML element using the `onclick` event. I was able to create the element on load, but find myself unable to with the event. Please lead me in the right direction. Here's my HTML page:

```
<html>
<body>

    <div id="d1">
        <p id="p1">Paragraph.</p>

    </div>
    <div id="d2">
        <label onclick="open()">Inbox</label>
    </div>

    <script>
        function open(){
            alert("Start");
            var para=document.createElement("p");
            var node=document.createTextNode("Text");
            para.appendChild(node);
            para.style.color="red";
            var element=document.getElementById("d2");
            element.appendChild(para);
                       }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`open()` seems to be a reserved functions. Tried with `open1()`, it works.

Comment: Excatly open is reserved thanx

Answer (score 2):

You are probably colliding with the window.open function built into the browser, rename your function.

Comment: thnaks for the answer...yes it was reserved word..as Shashank said...and u cleared that it was window.open

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<label onclick="create_elem();">Inbox</label>
<script language="javascript">
function create_elem(){
    alert("Start");
    var para=document.createElement("p");
    var node=document.createTextNode("Text");
    para.appendChild(node);
    para.style.color="red";
    var element=document.getElementById("d2");
    element.appendChild(para);
}
</script>
```